# autohotkey - More chars as a single hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Is there any way to map a sequence of chars to trigger events ?

I'd like to have 1 single special hotkey to remember `(e.g. Control-k)`
and with another letter after it, I can trigger different events:
ex

```
^km  --> do something 
^kp  --> do something else
^kc  --> do something else
...
```

Comment: also look into `hotstring`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
; The #If-directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings.
; #If is positional: it affects all hotkeys and hotstrings physically beneath it in the script.

#If GetKeyState("Ctrl")

    ; ^ka
    k & a:: MsgBox, Ctrl_k_a

    ; ^kb
    k & b:: MsgBox, Ctrl_k_b

#If   ; turn off context sensitivity
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm

Comment: That's a very useful info and it sounds much powerful. Thanks a lot! I'll practice around it, as my first attempts seem to require to press 3 keys all-together (e.g.: ^kp in 1 shot, works, but: ^ + some_ms_time + k + some_ms_time + p, opens my printer dialog on 'p'). Thanks again.